# Is there any way to get PVRTexTool's version from the command line?

Tags: unity

I am to make an automated task which involves requiring the version of the PVRTexTool that comes with the Unity installed in a machine.

Is it possible to get the version of PVRTexTool on the command shell?

Answer (score -1):

PVRTexTool as part of PowerVR Tool at Imagination website has command-line tools for Windows 32/64, Linux 32/64 and OSX 32.

https://community.imgtec.com/developers/powervr/tools/pvrtextool/

Comment: Which command provides the version?